# How do you subtract a count result from another count result to satisfy a where clause in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to include an IF statement in the very last subquery (or elsewhere if better suited) to exclude the rows being counted on **class_id** *IF* there is a corresponding *0* in the attendance column of the same table?

What I'm trying to do is if a 6 people have booked into a class (max size 6) but 1 has cancelled before the class - I want the result to be 5 thus showing the class as being available (why Im counting on the class ID and not attendance field)

```
SELECT c.*
FROM classes c
WHERE c.location_id = :location_id
AND (c.level_id = :current_level OR c.level_id = :previous_level OR c.level_id = :next_level)
AND c.datetime BETWEEN CURDATE() AND ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)
AND (c.class_id NOT IN (
     SELECT class_id 
     FROM swimmer_classes) 
     OR c.class_id IN (
                       SELECT class_id 
                       FROM swimmer_classes 
                       GROUP BY class_id 
                       HAVING COUNT(class_id) < 6))"
```

**Update 1**

swimmer_classes schema

```
swimmer_class_id   swimmer_id    class_id   attendance
1                  1             1          null           
2                  2             1          null
3                  3             1          null
4                  4             1          null
5                  5             1          null
6                  6             1          0
```

Result: Count(class_id) = 6

**Required Output**

Count required = 5 based on following Pseudo code

```
 Count(class_id) - Count(attendance of class_id) = 5
```

Comment: In last `SELECT` you'll have to perform a `JOIN` with your `attendance` table in order to achieve that.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clearer, attendance is a field in the swimmer_classes table so nothing to join to

Comment: please post schema, sample data, current output and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work in your scenario?

```
SELECT class_id 
FROM swimmer_classes
WHERE attendance <> 0 OR attendance is NULL
GROUP BY class_id 
HAVING COUNT(class_id) < 6
```

Alternatively the more long-winded:

```
SELECT class_id FROM 
(
    SELECT class_id, count(*) as cnt
    FROM swimmer_classes
    WHERE attendance <> 0 OR attendance is NULL
    GROUP BY class_id 
) t
where t.cnt < 6
```

Comment: No, that's excluding any class_id that has a record in the swimmer_classes table (whether its the one with the 0 in attendance or not).  What I'm trying to get it to do is count the class_id's then if there is a row with an attendance of 0 either skip that one row or subtract 1 from the count. See update

Comment: I'm confused - you said you are getting count as 6, but want count to be 5 - if you count the ones where attendance is not '0', you will get 5. "whether its the one with the 0 in attendance or not" - the whole point of the line "WHERE attendance <> 0" is that it doesn't count the ones with 0

Comment: Me too! I know how where clauses work - but when I add "WHERE attendance <> 0" to that query it returns 0 for class_id 1 which is why my question was is there a way to count(class_id) then minus count(class_id where attendance = 0) because it seems to count the attendance ok!

Comment: Ah I think I might know the problem - some databases don't treat NULL as a value, so any kind of value comparison will not find nulls - you can either set the attendance of the attending people to 1 instead of NULL, or change the query to say "WHERE attendance <> 0 or attendance is NULL" - see updated query

Comment: hehehe I just tried this WHERE (attendance IS null or attendance = 2) GROUP BY class_id HAVING COUNT(class_id) <6 and it worked.  As did your update!